# "resources" folder not being created in WEB-INF directory in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application in development that I recently upgraded from Spring 3 to Spring 4 (spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.5.RELEASE to 1.4.6.RELEASE).

I have, within my `src/main/resources/templates` directory, an html template (called 'test-template.html') which I have been using to create HTML email content, using Thymeleaf's TemplateEngine. (This was working fine prior to upgrading to version 4.)

The problem I have at present is that no "templates" directory is being created within WEB-INF on the server (or within the relevant directory within "target", upon building with Maven). As a result, I'm getting the following:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/test-template.html]

The following is my configuration class for Thymeleaf. (I am using manual configuration since I'm using Thymeleaf only for email template processing, and thus don't want Spring Boot to configure a Thymeleaf view resolver. I get the same error with auto-configuration, however.)

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThymeleafConfig.class);

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Here's the pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>blah blah</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.matchingchina.AcumenApplication</start-class>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WEBJARS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Try to remove "/WEB-INF/" in your ITemplateResolver. You want to look for src/main/resources/templates but your error is saying /WEB-INF/templates/test-template.html]

Comment: are you building a jar or a war?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, but to no avail. 

I think the problem lies in the pom.xml file, but I can't see where. I'll edit my question to add it in.

Comment: @Jaiwo99 a WAR. I've added the pom.xml to the original question.

Comment: change `"/WEB-INF/templates/"` to `classpath:/template/` on the `classpath` doesn't necessary on the web context path

Comment: then unzip your war, check where it is

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Worked like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: @Jaiwo99 (I realised I had a typo when I first tried to implement your suggestion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/WEB-INF/templates/` to `classpath:/template/`. On the classpath doesn't necessary mean on the web context path.